# Best practice for "get" functions

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am new to Python.

Assume I have a dictionary which holds power supply admin state. 
(OK = Turned on. FAIL  = Turned off).

There are several way to write the "get" function:

**1st way**

```
is_power_supply_off(dictionary)
  gets the admin state from dictionary.
  returns true if turned off.
  returns false if turned on.

is_power_supply_on(dictionary)
  gets the admin state from dictionary.
  returns true if turned on.
  returns false if turned off.
```

**2nd way**

```
is_power_supply_on_or_off(dictionary, on_or_off)
  gets the admin state from dictionary.
  returns true/false based on the received argument
```

**3rd way**

```
get_power_supply_admin_state(dictionary)
  gets the admin state from dictionary.
  return value.
```

Then, I can ask in the function which calls the get function

```
if get_power_supply_admin_state() == turned_on/turned_off...
```

My questions are:

Which of the above is considered best practice?

If all three ways are OK, and it`s just a matter of style, please let me know.

Is 1st way considered as "code duplication"? I am asking this because I can combine the two functions to be just one (by adding an argument, as I did in the 2nd way. Still, IMO, 1st way is more readable than 2nd way.

I will appreciate if you can share your thoughts on EACH of the ways I specified.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you thinking of 'admin state' as being a stored boolean or something that has to be evaluated?

Comment: I guess the second and third methods would be preferred over the first one.

Comment: SuperBiasedMan, your comment is correct. I edited the question so it will be more clear. Please share your thoughts on this.

Comment: I would say just have `is_power_supply_on` and use `not is_power_supply_on` for `off`.

Comment: If this is a boolean, then the 3rd way is the way to go.  Return a boolean and from the method name make it clear what that boolean means ie. `is_power_supply_on()`.  If you want to test the opposite, then you just negate that answer when calling it.

Comment: Added an answer, but in general if you have exact code it can be more helpful to understand your needs than pseudocode. With the pseudocode, some people presumed you were storing a boolean and went off on the wrong track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that the best approach would be to have only a `is_power_supply_on` function.  Then, to test if it is off, you can do `not is_power_supply_on(dictionary)`.

This could even be a lambda (assuming `state` is the key of the admin state)::

```
is_power_supply_on = lambda mydict: mydict['state'].lower() == 'ok'
```

The problem with the first approach is that, as you say, it wastes codes.

The problem with the second approach is that, at best, you save two characters compared to `not` (if you use `0` or `1` for `on_or_off`), and if you use a more idiomatic approach (like `on=True` or `on_or_off="off") you end up using more characters.  Further, it results in slower and more complicated code since you need to do an`if` test.

The problem with the third approach is in most cases you will also likely be wasting characters compared to just getting the `dict` value by key manually.

Comment: Yep, this seems ideal. Avoids the code duplication of the first approach, and avoids having to create some kind of "power state" enum, like you'd need for the second and third approaches.

Comment: TheBlackCat, thank you! Do you have a recommendation for an book on writing reusable code?

Comment: Probably "Idiomatic Python".

Comment: The book you recommended focuses on popular used "pythonic" ways for solving common problems. I talked about "reusable code", which is different...

Comment: I don't know then, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Even if this solution isn't in your propositions, I think the most pythonic way of creating getters is to use properties. As it, you'll be able to know whether the power supply is on or off, but the user will use this property as it was a simple class member:

```
@property
def state(self):
    # Here, get whether the power supply is on or off
    # and put it in value
    return value
```

Also, you could create two class constants, `PowerSupply.on = True` and `PowerSupply.off = False`, which would make the code easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

The general Pythonic style is to not repeat yourself unnecessarily, so definitely the first method seems pointless because it's actually confusing to follow (you need to notice whether it's on or off)

I'd gravitate most to

```
get_power_supply_admin_state(dictionary)
  gets the admin state from dictionary
  return value
```

And, if I'm reading this correctly, you could go even further.

```
power_supply_on(dictionary)
  return the admin state from dictionary == turned on
```

This will evaluate to True if it's on and False otherwise, creating the simplest test because then you can run

```
if power_supply_on(dictionary):
```

Answer (score 0):

It's more Pythonic to store the dictionary in a class:

```
class PowerSupply(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.state = {'admin': 'FAIL'}

    def turn_on(self):
        self.state['admin'] = 'OK'

    def is_on(self):
        return self.state['admin'] == 'OK'
```

(add more methods as needed)

Then you can use it like this:

```
ps = PowerSupply()
if not ps.is_on():
    # send an alert!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result = is_power_supply_off(state)
result = is_power_supply_on(state)
result = not is_power_supply_on(state)  # alternatively, two functions are certainly not needed
```

I strongly prefer this kind of naming for sake of readability. Let's just consider alternatives, not in function definition but where function is used.

```
result = is_power_supply_on_or_off(state, True)
    pass
result = is_power_supply_on_or_off(state, False)
    pass
if get_power_supply_admin_state(state):
    pass
if not get_power_supply_admin_state(state):
    pass
```

All of these codes requires map of what `True` and `False` means in this context. And to be honest, is not that clear. In many embedded systems `0` means truthy value. What if this function analyses output from system command? `0` (falsy) value is indicator of correct state/execution. In a result, intuitive `True` means OK is not always valid. Therefore I strongly advice for first option - precisely named function.

Obviously, you'll have some kind of private function like `_get_power_supply_state_value()`. Both function will call it and manipulate it's output. But point is - it will be hidden inside a module which knows what means what considering power supply state. Is implementation detail and API users does not need to know it.